# Let $A,B,C,D,E$ be five points marked in clockwise direction on the unit crcle in the plane wth centre at origin.

Tags: geometry

Let $A,B,C,D,E$ be five points marked in  clockwise direction on the unit circle in the plane with centre at origin. If $f(P)=\alpha x+\beta y$ for $P=(x,y)$

If $f(A)=10,f(B)=5,f(C)=4,f(D)=10$. What is $f(E)$?

Please help on how to start

Comment: I do not see any dependency between those points. It seems to me, that $f(E)$ is impossible to find. We only know $E = (x_0,y_0)$ for some $x_0,y_0 \in \mathbb{R}, \sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2)} = 1$. I assume $\alpha, \beta$ are the same for each point, but don't know how would the knowledge of them help us, since we would only have $\alpha x_0 + \beta y_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Your function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is a linear projection of the plane onto a line. In such a projection, the preimage for any point on the line is a whole line, and all these preimage lines are parallel to one another. One such line passes through $A$ and $D$, since their projection is the same. $B$ and $C$ result in smaller values, since they lie on one side of that line. $E$ lies on the other side, so one fact you know is that $f(E)>10$.

Unless you know more details about the positions on the circle, that's all you can tell. If the points were marked at equal angles, so they form a regular pentagon, then you could give more detail. In that case, however, you'd have $BC\parallel AD$ and therefore $f(B)=f(C)$. So you can even rule out a regular pentagon with what you know from the problem statement.